# Why was Darth Vader so much taller than Anakin Skywalker?

Tags: star-wars, darth-vader

In A New Hope, Darth Vader is seen as extremely tall. He is perhaps close to 7' tall, although other sources cite his height closer to 6'8.

In episodes 2 and 3, we see Anakin is the height of a normal sized man. Why would he be so much taller as Darth Vader?

Comment: Why not? Anakin had all of his limbs chopped off.

Comment: Why be rebuilt at 5'11" when you can be rebuilt at 7'?

Comment: @ChristopherLee Well, seeing as height is more than just leg length, being made a foot or more taller might make you look weird proportionally. Your arms and legs would be really long and your torso would be much shorter than you'd think.

Comment: I think 7' is a bit much. David Prowse is 6'5", so Vader is probably not much more than that.

Comment: @KSmarts Indeed. Everything I've read says that Vader is 2m tall in his armor. That's 6'8".

Comment: Because Darth Vader is an imposing, indimidating badass, and young Anakin is a whiny little bitch.

Comment: What's funny is that everyone on the Death Star treats this badass as a hopeless yokel.

Comment: He uses Gene Simmons' KISS platform shoes.

Comment: For reference, Hayden Christensen is 6'2". As @phantom42 notes, Vader is 6'8" (including armored boots and tall helmet?). So, it's really only 6 inches we're looking at, and **what guy wouldn't want 6 more inches?**

Comment: Light sabers, light loafers.

Comment: Short answer:  They made him taller the same way people turned [this](http://www.trickybiz.com/userfiles/image/delorean%20pic.jpg) DeLorean into [this](http://cdn4.nerdapproved.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/deLorean.jpg?bbba63) DeLorean limousine.

Comment: and also there's Sebastian Shaw, who's about 6' 2" and who played the redeemed Anakin Skywalker in ROTJ

Comment: @WadCheber Second link broken...

Comment: @Michael http://nerdapproved.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/deLorean.jpg

Comment: Robostilts all the way

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Keep in mind that the being we know as Darth Vader is not simply Anakin Skywalker in a suit. Anakin's physical body was used as the foundation, true, but Darth Vader is much more:

- Both of Anakin's legs were removed and replaced with robotic prostheses.
- Vader's armor is quite thick and likely adds an inch or more to both his height AND overall girth (torso, legs, arms, etc.), thus making him appear both taller and bulkier
- Vader's overall look is designed to be large and intimidating, thus making him a more effective symbol of the Emperor's power

Given these facts, it's not difficult to see how a 6'1" Anakin could become a 6'8" Vader. **There are approximately 5-6 inches added at the feet and helmet alone, so the remaining inch or two could easily be dispersed throughout the shins & legs.**

[image]

Comment: Armoring the soles may be necessary in order to protect the circuitry from fire or other environmental conditions. Regardless, the soles alone - even unarmored - are quite thick and would add height. As anyone who's worn thick boots and/or armor would tell you - it all adds up to make you a few inches taller.

Comment: @Oldcat I've worn work/steel toe boots that have at *least* 1 inch soles, and my boots don't need to hide or protect mechanical apparatuses. Also, if you look at the pics of Vader getting electrocuted by the Emperor, you can see that his helmet is at least an inch higher than the top of his head. There's 2-4 inches accounted for there. The rest could easily be distributed among his shins, thighs, and lower spine/waist.

Comment: If his legs were removed, the replacements could be slightly longer.

Comment: @Oldcat - He has no legs.  His lower half is all mechanical.

Comment: @Oldcat - from Wookieepedia:  Additionally, the tall boots were a poor fit for his artificial feet, whose toes lacked the electrostatic sensitivity of his equally false fingertips. These devices made it even more difficult for him to move with ease, much less with any grace. Raised in the heel, the cumbersome footwear canted him slightly forward, forcing him to move with exaggerated caution lest he stumble or topple over

Comment: Extra couple of inches makes all the difference

Comment: @ATB - That's what she said.

Comment: "https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/157813/46383" someone wants to know what the source for that Darth Vader image is.

Comment: Nice answer. An easier one would be - choosing Hayden was the *worst* mistake of all time.

Answer (score 9):

Based on everything I've read, Hayden Christensen is 6 feet even or 6'1". Prowse, at the time of the filming of the original Star Wars, was 6'6". Anakin Skywalker is roughly nineteen at the beginning of Episode 2 and roughly 24 by the end of Episode 3.

Human males can grow into their mid twenties, so the idea that Vader as he stands by the end of Episode 3 is taller than Anakin at the beginning of Episode 2 is perfectly reasonable. Both of my sons grew substantially after eighteen and into their early twenties.

Most importantly, the actor's height is not the character's height. Darth Vader was played by three different people in the original trilogy, only one of which was six and half feet tall. Most of his fighting was done by Bob Anderson in *Empire Strikes Back* and *Return of the Jedi*, who was only 6'1. Anderson wore lifts, but was probably not as tall as Prowse even so. The 6'10" soccer player in *Invictus* played by Matt Damon was not short because he was played by the sub-six foot Damon. Camera tricks were used throughout to make him appear taller.

Christensen, at 6'1, is also substantially taller than many of his castmates. He did not look short in either Episodes 2 or 3. He was visibly taller than Obi-Wan and Palpatine, more than the less-than-three-inch height difference of the actors would suggest (Guinness, MacGregor, and McDiarmid are all 5'10). Christensen still towered over the 5'3" Portman, and scenes with them walking together certainly made him look very tall.

Finally, Skywalker's height on Wookieepedia is 1.88 meters (roughly 6'2), while Vader's is 2.02 meters, but Vader's height includes his helmet and boots, which he is never without, and 2.02 meters comes out to 6'6" roughly, making Vader in the helmet and boots as tall as Prowse without. That would put a fully grown Anakin with proportional limbs (Vader's limbs are proportional; his torso is that of a very large and tall man, which Prowse was, and he is always drawn as such, so the idea that they used longer limbs to make him so tall does not fit, as it would render a taller, narrower figure). Realistically, Vader without his helmet and boots would be about six three (an inch and a half for the boots and an inch and a half for the helmet, which sat atop an under-helmet/mask), so you're looking at only an inch difference at most.

Comment: and also there's Sebastian Shaw, who's about 6' 2" and who played the redeemed Anakin Skywalker in ROTJ

Answer (score 3):

Hayden Christensen is 6'2".  David Prowse is 6'5".  That's only a 3" difference.

Comment: One which we assume is mostly given by the helmet height

Comment: Yeah, so? (I think the conclusion is missing here).

Comment: According to IMDB and GossipGist Hayden's height is exactly 6' and not 6'2". https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0159789/ and https://gossipgist.com/hayden-christensen#:~:text=Body%20Measurements%20of%20Hayden%20Christensen,has%20an%20athletic%20body%20build.

Answer (score 0):

Darth Vader's height is listed at 2.02 meters which is 6'7.5". Since the first actor in the Vader suit was David Prowse, then 6'6", it's wholly believable that Vader is 6'7.5" (at most). Hayden Christensen's height is between 6'0" and 6'1" depending on the source. Not only do Vader's artificial parts make him taller, they give him a "straighter spine", and prevent him from shrinking. So Vader is the same height when he wakes up, as he is throughout the rest of the day.

Comment: Where are these numbers sources from?

Answer (score -2):

Well he got almost all his limbs cut off so the emperor use that to his advantage and made darth Vader taller so he would be more intimidating

Comment: Makes sense but could you find proof.