# Where is this Darth Vader image from?

Tags: star-wars, technology, image-identification

I saw this image in [an answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/79019/why-was-darth-vader-so-much-taller-than-anakin-skywalker/79034#79034) on another question

[image: An X-ray view style drawing of Darth Vader's head and helmet, with a description about the helmet next to it. Part of a drawing of the feet and lower legs is also visible.]

**Where is it from?** I am not a highly vested Star Wars fan but I am a person who is very interested in the back stories and physical abilities or devices used with certain characters and stories.

Comment: Why do his mechanical feet need toes, anyway, if he always wears boots over them?

Comment: The answers beat me to it, but yeah, it's from the Blueprint collection book. I found the scan online, but have the book as well. The image I used in my answer was a mashup of the top and bottom parts (head & feet), but I don't remember if I found it that way or did it myself in Photoshop.

Answer (score 10):

That image is from [Star Wars Blueprints: The Ultimate Collection](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Blueprints:_The_Ultimate_Collection), published by DK Books.

The full panel is show below.

[image]

If you're interested in Darth specifically, you might also want to consider getting hold of the [Darth Vader: A 3-D Reconstruction Log](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Vader:_A_3-D_Reconstruction_Log) factbook. It shows Vader in great detail and covers every part of his bodysuit.

Answer (score 7):

This appears to be from [Star Wars Blueprints: The Ultimate Collection](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Blueprints:_The_Ultimate_Collection).

While I don't have a copy to 100% confirm this against the contents of the book, the cover art matches the image.

[image]